# Need help to integrate a particular vendor's Javadoc to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I'm working on big Java enterpriseware ([MatrixOne / ENOVIA V6](http://www.3ds.com/products/enovia/products/enovia-v6/), if you mind). The maintainers provide some kind of Javadoc, which looks like very vanilla Javadoc, and I can read it as HTML in my browser.

However, I'm unable to integrate it to Eclipse, which is painful because I have to make round-trips to my browser. In Eclipse, I just get the dreaded `Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.`:
[image]

After [learning](https://superuser.com/questions/167458/how-to-add-javadocs-to-eclipse) that Javadoc can be defined at project and `.jar` level, I tried to do both, knowing that:

1. the javadoc folder contains [a `package-list` file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13140569/enovia-javadoc-missing-eclipse/package-list), which seems to sanely define the documented packages
2. the javadoc folder contains the typical folder/subfolder package structure, itself containing `ClassName.html` files. E.g. the `com.matrixone.apps.domain` line of my `package-list` file is matched by a `com/matrixone/apps/domain` structure, containing lots of `ClassName.html` files
3. the javadoc folder doesn't contain a `index.html` file

When I try to define my Javadoc, the `Validate...` button fails because of a missing `index.html`. Then if I create a dummy `index.html` file, validation works, but I still cannot see the Javadoc when hovering a vendor class/method.

So my question is: *What's missing to get this skewed Javadoc to display in Eclipse?* Sub-questions I see at this point are:

1. Was it a bad idea to create a dummy `index.html` file? If yes, what should I do? (i.e. what tags/meta-information does Eclipse expect?)
2. A quick comparison of a standard Javadoc file ([`String.html`](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13140569/enovia-javadoc-missing-eclipse/String.html)) vs. one of those vendor Javadoc ([`DomainObject.html`](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13140569/enovia-javadoc-missing-eclipse/DomainObject.html)) reveals that meta-information possibly used by Eclipse is absent from my javadoc. For example, my vendor Javadoc includes none of the many `<meta>` tags present in the `String.html` Javadoc `<head>`.
   → **Does somebody know the logic/heuristic** used by Eclipse to fetch a method/class Javadoc? **Maybe point me to the code?** With this information I may be able to figure out what's wrong in my Javadoc, and hopefully fix it.
3. Anything you see fit if you ever faced a similar problem.

I'm currently using Eclipse Juno SR1 on Java 7, under Windows 7.

Of course, feel free to comment to ask for information I forgot to include. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you show that javadoc? Are you specifying Javadoc URL or Javadoc in archive? I had previously no problems specifying Javadoc for 3rd party libraries in Eclipse. Strange ...

Comment: I'm specifying a Javadoc URL: `file:/C:/enoviaV6R2012x/javadoc/Doc/docs/api/`. Regarding the Javadoc itself, I prefer not to fully upload it, I'm pretty sure it's copyrighted/non-redistributable, but I linked to one example ([`DomainObject.html`](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13140569/enovia-javadoc-missing-eclipse/DomainObject.html)) and the [`packages-list`](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13140569/enovia-javadoc-missing-eclipse/package-list).

Comment: In other words you have a JAR archive locally? Usually it should be either URL (on the web) or path to local **archive**. Again, is it a JAR file?

Comment: @informatik01 sorry for not answering that part of the question. My javadoc is *not* a JAR file, it is a directory containing a `packages-list` file and a set of html files and directories.

Comment: For instance, I can successfully specify **Javadoc URL** location for JDOM library like this: http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/ and it works. If I use a local _jdom-2.0.4-javadoc.jar_ archive, then I would choose an option "Javadoc in archive" in Eclipse and specify a path to that JAR (better put that JAR in _lib_ folder in your project). As for the "Path within archive" in the latter case, it would be just `/`.

Comment: OK but anyway, I think Eclipse is OK with my local folder (that the file picker automatically interprets as the above-mentioned `file:/` address), since the `Validate...` button recognizes my `packages-list`+`index.html` couple. Do you nevertheless suggest the fact that I don't use a JAR may be the cause of my problem?

Comment: It's just I always used either URL for the web (my preference) or download an **archive**. It's weird that in your case there is no `index.html` file. The standard way (e.g. like the description you provided) should've worked. Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: By the way, another issue that is probably may cause a problem, is that the **path to your javadoc folder should not contain spaces**. Maybe this is the cause ... And if it is a local file then usually you should choose "Javadoc in archive" option in Eclipse

Comment: OK, maybe I'll give a try to packaging as a JAR and feeding it to Eclipse. And no, the path doesn't include any space, neither to arrive to `packages-list`, nor down the tree :-/ . Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Em, "Javadoc in archive" is still for JAR and ZIP archive. In your case it's indeed an URL. Just tried unpacking JAR to a folder, used URL in the form `file:/some/path` and it worked like a charm ...

Comment: Anything useful in the error log view?

Comment: @MiserableVariable no, the `Error Log` view (showing `Workspace log`) displays a few unrelated validation and repository errors, but nothing close to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem; however, I didn't try to solve it by using a local copy of the JavaDoc for JDOM.  Instead, I was trying to use the appropriate URL (the JavaDoc URL for the current version of JDOM is http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/).  So, on the jdom.jar library in the Java Build Path configuration for my Eclipse project, I configured the URL and hit the Validate button.  Eclipse seemed to think it was valid, but I still got the same error about not having any attached JavaDoc.

I then discovered that jdom.org also has the JavaDoc for an older version of JDOM (http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/). So, I tried that on the jdom.jar library JavaDoc configuration and that worked!

The lesson I learned was that the version of the library appears to be taken into consideration when Eclipse is deciding whether the configured JavaDoc is utilized (considered to be attached or not).  **Make sure the library version matches the version of the JavaDoc for the library** (seems obvious now that I've found it).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I no longer work with / have access to that specific product and JavaDoc. Being unable to test your suggestion, the best I can do is to +1 your answer, and signal your answer to ex-colleagues. I hope one of them will be able to test it. Thanks again!